# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\beta \sin(x)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\beta \sin(x)}\mathrm{d}x$

Using Wolfram, I get a very complex result. Obviously the integration for

$$
\int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\sin(x)} \mathrm{d}x= x-\cos(x) + C
$$

However, when there is a constant $\beta$ that is greater than $1$ in my case, in front of the sine term, it becomes very complex. I'm wondering if there is a better approach to solving this problem. And this is also a definite integral and $x$ is in a certain interval. So my problem is,

$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\beta \sin(x)}\mathrm{d}x
$$

where $\beta > 1 $.

Comment: See [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) which will work so long as $x_1,x_2$ are between $\pm\frac\pi2$

Comment: When $\beta>1$, the definite integral would probably become improper integral.

Comment: I think you may want an indefinite integral.

Comment: @SundayLi that should be correct. Indeed what I work on formally goes to infinity at one point if I cover the whole range. However, I want to exclude that part and calculate the definite part by choosing limits accordingly.

Comment: I mean you could calculate $\int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\beta\sin(x)} \mathrm{d}x$ first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
I & = \int \dfrac{\cos^2x}{1-\beta \sin x} dx\\
& = \int \dfrac{1-\sin^2x}{1-\beta \sin x} dx\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \int \dfrac{(1-\beta \sin x)(1+ \beta \sin x) +(\beta^2 -1)}{1-\beta \sin x} dx\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \int \left( 1+\beta \sin x + \dfrac{(\beta^2 -1)}{1-\beta \sin x} \right) dx \\
& = \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \left( x - \beta \cos x + (\beta^2-1) \int \dfrac{dx}{1-\beta \sin x} \right)\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \left( x - \beta \cos x + (\beta^2-1) \int \dfrac{ \sec^2 (\frac x2)}{1+\tan^2(\frac x2)-2\beta \tan (\frac x2)} dx \right)\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \left( x - \beta \cos x + 2(\beta^2-1) \int \dfrac{\frac12 \sec^2 (\frac x2)}{(\tan(\frac x2)-\beta)^2 + 1-\beta^2} dx \right)\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \left( x - \beta \cos x + 2(\beta^2-1) \int \dfrac{du}{u^2 + 1-\beta^2} \right) \hspace{2 cm}\left[ u = \tan(\frac x2)-\beta \right]\\
& \\
I &= 
     \begin{cases}
       \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \left( x - \beta \cos x + \sqrt{\beta^2-1} \ln \left| \dfrac{u-\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}{u+\sqrt{\beta^2-1}} \right| \right) + C &\quad\text{if } |\beta| \ge 1\\
       \dfrac{1}{\beta^2} \left( x - \beta \cos x -2 \sqrt{\beta^2-1} \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} \right) \right) + C &\quad\text{if } |\beta| \le 1 \\
     \end{cases}
\end{align}

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! Now I understand how to deal with these types of integrals. Would you have any resource suggestions for me to practice these?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of $\cos^2 x$, we split the integrand into two.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{\beta^2} \int \frac{\left(1-\beta^2 \sin ^2 x\right)+\left(\beta^2-1\right)}{1-\beta \sin x} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{\beta^2}  \underbrace{\int(1+\beta \sin x) d x}_{x-\beta \cos x} +\frac{\beta^2-1}{\beta^2} \int \frac{d x}{1-\beta \sin x}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{1-\beta \sin x}&=\int \frac{1+\beta \sin x}{1-\beta \sin ^2 x} d x \\
& =\int \frac{d x}{1-\beta^2 \sin ^2 x}+\beta \int \frac{\sin x d x}{1-\beta^2 \sin ^2 x} \\
& =-\int \frac{d(\cot x)}{\left(1-\beta^2\right)+\cot ^2 x}-\int \frac{d(\beta \cos x)}{\left(1-\beta^2\right)+(\beta \cos x)^2} \\
& = \begin{cases}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cot x}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\beta \cos x}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)\right] & \text { if }|\beta|<1 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}\left[\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cot x}{\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}\right)+\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\beta \cos x}{\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}\right)\right] & \text { if }|\beta|>1\end{cases} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we can conclude that
$$\boxed{I = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\beta^2}(x-\beta \cos x)+\frac{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}{\beta^2}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cot x}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\beta \cos x}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)\right] & \text { if }|\beta|<1 \\
\frac{1}{\beta^2}(x-\beta \cos x)+\frac{\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}{\beta^2}\left[\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cot x}{\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}\right)+\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\beta \cos x}{\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}\right)\right] & \text { if }|\beta|>1\end{cases} }$$

Comment: Thank you, I believe this corresponds to Sandipan's comment but looks like a more complicated version. I do not know if it gets simpler than Sandipan's result. Thanks again!